# How to arrange and assert MustBeCalled for property setter in JustMock

Tags: unit-testing, justmock

I have a mocked class with a property that has a get and set. My code under test calls the setter to assign a connection string value. My test code mocks the class that contains the property and I add MustBeCalled when I arrange the mock.

ViewModel Code:

```
public class ClientViewModel
{
    private readonly IMgmtDataProvider dataProvider;

    public ClientViewModel(IMgmtDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        this.dataProvider = dataProvider;            
    }
    private string clientConnectionString;
    public string ClientConnectionString
    {
        get { return clientConnectionString; }

        set
        {
            clientConnectionString = value;
            if (dataProvider != null)
                dataProvider.ClientConnectionString = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Test Code:

```
//Arrange
const string connectionString = "THIS IS MY CONNECTIONSTRING";
var mockedDataProvider = Mock.Create<IMgmtDataProvider>();
Mock.Arrange(() => mockedDataProvider.ClientConnectionString).MustBeCalled();

//Act
var testViewModel = new ClientViewModel(mockedDataProvider);
testViewModel.ClientConnectionString = connectionString;

//Assert
var callCount = Mock.GetTimesCalled(() => mockedDataProvider.ClientConnectinString);
Assert.IsTrue(callCount > 0);
```

my Mock.Arrange(...).MustBeCalled(); appears to be applied to the getter, not the setter. So, when I call Mock.GetTimesCalled(...), it returns 0. I need to apply the MustBeCalled to the setter instead of the getter. I want to assure the dataprovider's connectionstring is getting set when the viewmodel's connection string gets set. How do I tell JustMock to track how many times a mocked setter is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setters are arranged using the `Mock.ArrangeSet()` method, like so:

```
Mock.ArrangeSet(() => mockedDataProvider.ClientConnectionString = Arg.AnyString).MustBeCalled();
....
Mock.Assert(mockedDataProvider); // assert all expectations on this mock
```

You can also use `Mock.AssertSet()` as an alternative to the `ArrangeSet().MustBeCalled()` combo.

And finally, there's the `Mock.GetTimesSetCalled()` method for getting the number of times that a setter was called.

Check out the [documentation on property mocking](http://www.telerik.com/help/justmock/basic-usage-mock-properties.html) for examples.